# npm update --save replaces ~ with ^ in package.json

Tags: npm-update

There are two dependencies (with ~) in package.json file:

```
"monaco-editor": "~0.36.1",
"zone.js": "~0.11.8"
```

After `npm update --save` the dependency versions are replaced with (^):

```
"monaco-editor": "^0.36.1",
"zone.js": "^0.11.8"
```

node -v: v18.16.1
npm -v: 9.5.1

Answer (score 0):

You are hitting with https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/19585. However, you should be able to suppress with `--no-save` switch or re-run same command after `npm config set save-prefix=""` which suppresses auto-prefix.